# ajax 'url' issue (I think)

Tags: php, ajax, url

Got a question re submitting forms using ajax. I am trying to submit a 'contact' form using jquery/ajax. I got some code online and would like to tailor it to my needs. It seems that the 'url' parameter for the ajax function is not working properly. When I enter the full url for the php code, ajax throws and error, but when I enter a fake url, the ajax code executes (without, obviously, sending any information). So, let me show the form I have and the ajax code. I also have a php file, where the actual processing is done. The php file right now does nothing other than 'return true'. Please, take a look at the ajax code and see if you find anything obvious. Thx a lot.

HTML:

```
<div class="container"> 
  <!-- Contacts -->
  <div id="contacts">
    <div class="row"> 
      <!-- Alignment -->
      <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6"> 
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <p>Thank you for contacting <em>Make it to the Finish Line</em>. We will get back to you within 24 hours.</p>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <!-- Form itself -->
          <form name="sentMessage" class="well" id="contactForm" novalidate ><!--action="contactcode.php" method="POST">-->
            <legend>Contact Form</legend>
            <div class="control-group">
              <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" id="name" /><!--required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name" />-->
                <p class="help-block"></p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
              <div class="controls">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
              <div class="controls">
                <textarea rows="10" cols="100" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" id="message"></textarea><!--required 
                data-validation-required-message="Please enter your message" minlength="5" data-validation-minlength-message="Min 5 characters" 
                maxlength="999" style="resize:none"></textarea>-->
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="success"> </div>
            <!-- For success/fail messages -->
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Send</button>
            <br />
          </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

AJAX:

```
$(function() {
    $("input,textarea").jqBootstrapValidation(
    {
        preventSubmit: true,
        submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
        // something to have when submit produces an error ?
        // Not decided if I need it yet
    },
    submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
        // get values from FORM
        var name = $("input#name").val();
        var email = $("input#email").val();
        var message = $("textarea#message").val();
        var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
        // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
        if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
            firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "./php/contactcode.php",
            data: {name: name, email: email, message: message},
            cache: false,
            success: function() {
                // Success message
                $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                .append( "</button>");
                $('#success > .alert-success')
                .append("<strong>Message sent successfully. Thank you again. </strong>");
                $('#success > .alert-success')
                .append('</div>');
                //clear all fields
                $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
            },
            error: function() { 
                // Fail message
                $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                .append( "</button>");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').append("<strong>Sorry "+firstName+" it seems that my mail server is not responding...</strong> Please email me directly to <a href='mailto:ralf.riedel@usm.edu?Subject=error from MITTFL contact form'>ralf.riedel@usm.edu</a>. Sorry for the inconvenience.");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
                //clear all fields
                $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
            },
        })
        },
        filter: function() {
            return $(this).is(":visible");
        },
    });
    $("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab("show");
    });
});
    /*When clicking on Full hide fail/success boxes */
    $('#name').focus(function() {
        $('#success').html('');
});
```

Comment: What does the console.log say to you?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
url: "./php/contactcode.php",
```

to

```
url: "/php/contactcode.php",
```

And change the success function to this (just to make it more clean)

```
$('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button><strong>Message sent successfully. Thank you again. </strong></div>");
```

Because append means to insert something inside this element (at the end). You appended the closing tag of an element inside it, I don't think this is a good practice.

Comment: I have tried that url and also tried to put the php code in the same directory as the js code (changed the url to 'contactcode.php'). When I do that, sure enough, the ajax 'success' executes, but not the php code. It seems like ajax is not invoking php. Well, unfortunately, it seems that there is nothing obviously wrong with my ajax. Thx.

Comment: In your code, you can say success: function(data) and then append the data somewhere. Then in php, `echo 'Success!'`. Use echo in PHP to return something to ajax.